# Could not resolve: org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6:3.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot

what is the problem, i just changed group name here, i get could not resolve for springsecuriy extras
i can't see why

```
plugins {
   id 'java'
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0'
   id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
   id 'org.hibernate.orm' version '6.1.5.Final'
   id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.18'
}

group = '*********'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
   implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6'
   runtimeOnly 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client'
   testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
   testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
   useJUnitPlatform()
}

hibernate {
   enhancement {
      lazyInitialization true
      dirtyTracking true
      associationManagement true
   }
}
```

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'. > Could not resolve org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6:3.1.0.RELEASE. Required by: project : > Could not resolve org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6:3.1.0.RELEASE. > Could not parse POM repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/thymeleaf/extras/… > Could not find org.springframework.security:spring-security-bom:6.0.0-RC2

I tried nothing it is made by spring initializer and boot version 3.0.0

Comment: I use graalvm-ce-17

Comment: Do you have (direct) access to maven central? (It is there: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6/3.1.0.RELEASE/ !) ..maybe your proxy/mirror (repo) not up2date?

Comment: I'm actually trying to update index in idea, url is, repo1.maven.org/maven2 
it get java.io error at 2% of update

Comment: Sorry my link was broken: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6/3.1.0.RELEASE/jar

Comment: Sounds like network/proxy(/firewall) issue ;(

Comment: > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6:3.1.0.RELEASE.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6:3.1.0.RELEASE.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/thymeleaf/extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6/3.1.0.RELEASE/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6-3.1.0.RELEASE.pom
            > Could not find org.springframework.security:spring-security-bom:6.0.0-RC2.

Comment: yes i think problems are from network too

Comment: i think real error is about this  Could not find org.springframework.security:spring-security-bom:6.0.0-RC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved problem by changing gradle build
i replaced repositories with this

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone"
    content {
        // Thymeleaf uses 6.0.0-RC2 of Security's bom in its dependency management
        includeModule("org.springframework.security", "spring-security-bom")
    }
}
```

}

I hope it help others

Comment: please (alternatively) try: `ext['spring-security6.version'] = '6.0.0'` (in build.gradle) (resp: `spring-security6.version=6.0.0` in gradle.properties) ..eventually according: `${spring-framework6.version}`

Comment: For the time being there is an issue with Thymeleaf relying on a RC candidate. This issue has been documented in Spring Boot (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33348).

Answer (score 3):

Thymeleaf 3.1.1 is released now, pls use

```
implementation("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6:3.1.1.RELEASE")
```

instead of

```
implementation("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5")
```